# The type or namespace name 'Startup' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I'm trying to add integration testing to my project but I keep getting the error "The type or namespace name 'Startup' cound not be found" in my Tests.cs file.

I have two project.json files, one in my src project and the other in my test project.

Src project.json looks like this:

```
{
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL": "1.0.2",
"Swashbuckle": "6.0.0-beta902" },
"tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
// "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"},
"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"]}},
"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true,
"debugType": "portable",
"xmlDoc": true},
"runtimeOptions": {
"configProperties": {
  "System.GC.Server": true
}},
"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "**/*.cshtml",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config",
  "Dockerfile.debug",
  "Dockerfile",
  "docker-compose.debug.yml",
  "docker-compose.yml"
]},
"scripts": {
"postpublish": [
  "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
]},
"tooling": {
 "defaultNamespace": "api"}}
```

The Test project.json looks like this:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"buildOptions": {
"debugType": "portable"},
"dependencies": {
"System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.1",
"xunit": "2.1.0",
"dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
"SrcService": {
  "target": "project"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.0.0"},
"testRunner": "xunit",
"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }
  },
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.4",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}}}
```

My Tests.cs class looks like this:

```
using System;
using Xunit;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;


namespace Tests
{
public class Tests
{
    public TestServer server { get; }
    public HttpClient client { get; }

    public Tests(){
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>();
        server = new TestServer(builder);
        client = server.CreateClient();
    }

[Fact]
public async void TestVisitRoot() {
    var response = await client.GetAsync("/");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
}}
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is your `Startup` class defined? you might need to add a `using` directive referring to your namespace or use full class name with namespace `Your.Namespace.Startup`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see in your `Project.json` in your test project

```json
"SrcService": {
   "target": "project"
}
```

So it means your Startup class is in this project.
In order to be recognized in your Test.cs you just need to add the `using`

```json
using [namespace the Startup class is in];
```

And that should be just this.

Hint: if you are using Visual Studio, when you have something not recognized like this. Just click on it and then press `CTRL + .` (or right click and `Quick action and refactoring` with VS2015)

Comment: 'Quick action and refactoring' is a good recommendation +1

Answer (score 11):

Check `namespace` of your `Startup.cs` it should be the same as in `Program.cs`.

Program.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;


namespace dotnetcoretester  // <------- This
{
    class Program
    {
     ...
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace dotnetcoretester // <------ and This
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add

> using ConsoleApplication;

at the top of the program.